# When downloading pyrebase on my M1 Mac, RSA throws an error. How can I fix this?

Tags: python, pip, pyrebase

When downloading pyrebase for flask development on Mac with M1 chip in a Rosetta terminal with the command:
`pip3 install pyrebase` I cannot install rsa.  I keep receiving the error:

```
  Using cached rsa-4.7.1.tar.gz (38 kB)
ERROR: Package 'rsa' requires a different Python: 2.7.16 not in '>=3.5, <4'
```

Is there a workaround for this issue?  I tried alternatively to pip3 install pyrebase4 but run into the same issue.

Comment: upvoting this to show some support for new members and new programmers willing to learn!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your python is not up to date:
Python: 2.7.16 not in '>=3.5, <4'
Check your repository if there is a newer version. If not, just download it and install it manually.
Remember that, if you have two versions, the newer one must be started locally.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to install rsa>=3.1.4 and then install module